# How to change text in textview each time in the loop from thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

My task was to make a counter, which will refresh the value each time in the loop from thread. Here's the code that I wrote:

```
thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            for (int i = 0; i<10;i++){
                                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                bundle.putInt("NUMBER", i);
                                Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), i+" ");
                                final int finalI = i;
                                textCounter.post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), finalI+" value set");
                                        textCounter.setText(String.valueOf(finalI));
                                    }
                                });
                                SystemClock.sleep(500);
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

The problem is that (how I saw in logger) firstly counter changes it's value from 0 to 9 and after all this values are added to `textView`. Probably I don't understand why it happens and what should to make program work correctly. Correctly I mean :

```
0 -> textView.add 0
1 -> textview.add 1

...

9 ->textView.add 9
```

But not

```
0
1
...
9

textview.add 0
textview.add 1
...
textview.add 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually sleep will not show any effect inside for loop in this case. What you have to do is create the loop with a delay to proceed to next value and post on textCounter normally. so the code should be like this...

```
thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    final int finalI=i;
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                            bundle.putInt("NUMBER", finalI);
                            Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), finalI + " ");
                            textCounter.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), finalI+" value set");
                                    textCounter.setText(String.valueOf(finalI));
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }, 500*i);
                }
            }
        }
        );
```